# The HTML element is also read by aria-label in Chrome

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

The HTML element is also read by aria-label in Chrome

```
  <div  [attr.aria-label]=“translations.content | translate"></div>
    
    translations.content = “<span>How are you</span>"
```

In Chrome, the voice-over reads span tag as well,

Would it be possible to have the voice-over read only the content?

Comment: can you try <span aria-hidden>test</span> not 100% it will hide from all screen readers
or do you want it to read the text test as well?

Comment: yes, only the text needs to be read

Comment: hmmm i can only think may be this  aria-roledescription="presentation" inside the span tag

Comment: The aria-label attribute is for interactive elements, landmarks, and widgets. If you run the Axe plugin to scan your code above, you will see a violation. But on a high level, what you are describing is not a sound objective. Your screen reader experience should not diverge from the sighted experience. Many users of screen readers have some vision, and you need to code for their experience as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, and `translations.content` is not null, you'll end up with:

`<div aria-label="<span>How are you</span>"></div>`

i.e., it looks like you are inserting a span element into an attribute value (which is not valid html), and chrome is guessing (wrongly) what you intended.

FWIW VoiceOver & Chrome is a combination which is known to misbehave at times. I think there have been some improvements, but anecdotally, VoiceOver plays better with Safari (or Firefox).

BTW `aria-label` is [not supported](https://html5accessibility.com/stuff/2020/11/07/not-so-short-note-on-aria-label-usage-big-table-edition/) on `div` unless an operable or landmark ARIA role has been added.